# Tools like binary decision diagrams for compression

Tags: compression, binary-data, binary-decision-diagram

I am looking for compression algorithms (of binary data with considerable regularity) that allows me to operate on the compressed data to quickly answer questions like: what is the value of the k'th bit of the input? how many bits are set? what is the intersection of this set with some other set?

An example of this type of algorithm is binary decision diagrams. I am wondering if there are others like that, maybe with more powerful operators.

Comment: [Zero-suppressed binary decision diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-suppressed_decision_diagram) are a flavor of binary decision diagrams that are more efficient for representing sparse sets. How would the "power" of "operators" be measured? Is there a particular example of application where the compression is needed? [Data compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression) methods may be relevant to this question.

Comment: 0-sup BDDs can be used to create an index of a dictionary that allows quite efficient searching (e.g. count or list all words with 6 letters having letter 'a' in a third place). We have an implementation to count or list all words with a given Levenshtein distance. Please, use PM if you are interested.